# Remove / Collapse bar at bottom of iOS simulator

Tags: ios, testing, webdriver, simulator

I can successfully run tests on the iOS simulator using webdriver, the only concern that I have is that there is a bar at the bottom of the screen which prevents the whole screen from displaying. It is not causing tests to fail, just wondering if there is a way to remove/collapse it so that the whole screen displays.

Comment: Are you using UITabBar in the bottom.

Comment: I do not know what the UITabBar is? It is just a grey bar at the bottom whenever I launch the webdriver iOS simulator.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Uitabbar then you can use:

```
[self hideTabBar:your tabbarcontroller];//call to hide the tabbar;
[self showTabBar:your tabbarcontroller];//call to show the tabbar;


  - (void)hideTabBar:(UITabBarController *) myTabbarController
    {
       [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
       [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

       for(UIView *myView in myTabbarController.view.subviews)
          {
             if([myView isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
               {
                  [myView setFrame:CGRectMake(myView.frame.origin.x, 480,
                   myView.frame.size.width,
                    myView.frame.size.height)];
                } 
               else 
                  {
                       [myView setFrame:CGRectMake(myView.frame.origin.x, 
                        myView.frame.origin.y,  
                        myView.frame.size.width, 480)];
                   }
           }

             [UIView commitAnimations];   
        }

   - (void)showTabBar:(UITabBarController *) tabbarcontroller
      {       
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        for(UIView *view in tabbarcontroller.view.subviews)
          {

            if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
             {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, 431, view.frame.size.width,
                view.frame.size.height)];

              } 
            else 
              {
                [view setFrame:CGRectMake(view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, 
                  view.frame.size.width, 431)];
              }
           }

          [UIView commitAnimations]; 
       }
```